# How do I pull specific entries in one dataframe and put them into a different blank dataframe?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes (for the purposes of this question, I've created some dummy ones. The real ones are much bigger). The first has all the data I need:

```
df1 <- data.frame("id" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                  "Label" = c("Bonds", "Cash", "Stock", "Equity", "Cash", "Bonds", 
                              "Bonds", "Cash", "Equity", "Stock"),
                  "Value" = c(.25, .25, .30, .20, .60, .40, .10, .40, .20, .30))
```

The second is a blank dataframe.

```
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 4))
```

My objective: each column in df2 should be associated with an "id" and each row should represent a "Label". The entries of df2 should be the respective "Value"s. In this example, df2 should look like this after the code has run:

```
           1       2      3
Bonds     .25     .40    .10
Cash      .25     .60    .40
Stock     .30     NA     .30
Equity    .20     NA     .20
```

Here's what I have so far. I created a vector that has the unique "id"s:

```
id <- unique(df1$id)
```

Then I create an ugly looking nested for loop that doesn't seem to work:

```
for (i in length(id)){
     for (j in 4){
          if (df1$id[j] == id[i] & df1$Label[j] == "Bonds"){
               df2[1, i] <- df1[j, 3]
          }
          else if (df1$id[j] == id[i] & df1$Label[j] == "Cash"){
               df2[2, i] <- df1[j, 3]
          }
          else if (df1$id[j] == id[i] & df1$Label[j] == "Stock"){
               df2[2, i] <- df1[j, 3]
          }
          else if (df1$id[j] == id[i] & df1$Label[j] == "Equity"){
               df2[2, i] <- df1[j, 3]
          }
     }
}
```

Running this code doesn't change anything. I don't get any errors. Am I doing this is the worst possible way? Why doesn't the ugly nested for loop do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `spread` from the `tidyr` package might be easier.

```
spread(df1, id, Value)

   Label    1   2   3
1  Bonds 0.25 0.4 0.1
2   Cash 0.25 0.6 0.4
3 Equity 0.20  NA 0.2
4  Stock 0.30  NA 0.3
```

Here is your fixed *ugly*-loop and some comments.

1. Your for-functions had just one value (length(id) and 4). If you want to loop you need more than one value (like 1:length(id) or 1:4).
   Your loop just looked at row 4 of df1 (1 - Equity - 0.2) and compared it with id 3.  There is no matching if condition for id1 == id3. Therefore your loop did nothing.
2. Since your second else if, you overwrote the same column (df2[2, i]).
3. Your for-function needs to iterate all over the df1. Your j stopped to early.

```
id <- unique(df1$id)

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 4))
colnames(df2) <- id
rownames(df2) <- c("Bonds", "Cash", "Stock", "Equity")

for (i in 1:length(id)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(df1)){
    if (df1$id[j] == id[i] & df1$Label[j] == "Bonds"){
      df2[1, i] <- df1[j, 3]
    }
    else if (df1$id[j] == id[i] & df1$Label[j] == "Cash"){
      df2[2, i] <- df1[j, 3]
    }
    else if (df1$id[j] == id[i] & df1$Label[j] == "Stock"){
      df2[3, i] <- df1[j, 3]
    }
    else if (df1$id[j] == id[i] & df1$Label[j] == "Equity"){
      df2[4, i] <- df1[j, 3]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The spread idea was amazing, but not what I needed. The points about the ugly for loops was EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `reshape` within base R

```
u <- reshape(df1,direction = "wide",idvar = "Label",timevar = "id")
df2 <- `row.names<-`(u[-1],u$Label)
```

which gives

```
> df2
   Label Value.1 Value.2 Value.3
1  Bonds    0.25     0.4     0.1
2   Cash    0.25     0.6     0.4
3  Stock    0.30      NA     0.3
4 Equity    0.20      NA     0.2
```